# How can you tell if someone is cutting you off from a wifi connection on your laptop or is it just a weak wifi signal?

Tags: wifi

I need your knowledge and/or opinions about this since I'm concerned if someone is doing it, or if the WiFi signal isn't strong.

My laptop is connected to WiFi that I do not own (they know that it is connected and they know it's me), and I am just watching YouTube videos, then after like 7 minutes I get disconnected from WiFi. When that happens, I just restart my laptop and it auto-connects to the WiFi.  The fastest that I got disconnected is when the moment I opened my Google Chrome browser.

My laptop is near to the modem/router. This is happening like when I feel like it's coming and it's kinda fast. Here are my questions about this:

1. I use an add-on VPN for my Google Chrome browser, does this affect my connection?
2. They use an Apple iPhone. Could it be that they're disconnecting it from the phone?
3. Does a USB WiFi adapter help, and is there a USB WiFi adapter without needing to put in WiFi info?
4. Is there any software that can help me detect if someone is cutting me off from the WiFi connection?
5. Maybe there's an app they use that can disconnect me from WiFi?
6. What are my defense options?
7. Maybe it is because of the brand of the laptop?

I've burnt out of questions for now, but there must be more. Please help.

I also just saw that my Internet connection got disconnected then reconnected again in just like 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: This is not a programming issue.  Probably better to ask on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like they are 'disconnecting' you. To me, I would first check the DHCP settings within the WiFi router, but if you don't own it, that might not be possible.

It sounds like you are unable to maintain a valid IP address. I think this is happening due to the fact that when you restart your machine, and request a new IP, it seems to work for a short period of time. It's a tough problem to troubleshoot without more information though.